# Deployment Failed in SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap, business-intelligence, olap-cube

[image]

I made an olap cube but unfortunately cannot deploy it. Can somebody tell me why does the deployment failed?

I am badly stuck at this and have no experience of working on it before

Answer (score 0):

The error message "The datasource ... contains an impersonation mode that is not supported for processing operations" points to the root cause: You need to edit the data source object(s) of your Analysis Services project and set the impersonation properties so that they work for the process running **on the Analysis Services server** (not your local computer) to connect to the relational database.